# How to stream word document in bytes stored in AWS S3 from boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ms-word, boto3

Using boto3, I am trying to retrieve a Microsoft Word document stored in S3.  However, when I try to access the object calling `client.get_object()` the content-length of Word Document is 0 while files with .txt extensions return the correct content-length.  Is there a way to decode the Word Document in order to write its output to a stream?

I have tested this with .txt files and .docs files and I have also tried using the .decode() method after reading the file, but based on the content being returned, there doesn't seem to be anything to decode.

Accessing a .txt Document I notice that the content-length is 17 (the number of characters in the file) and they can be read by calling txt_file.read()

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
txt_file = s3.get_object(Bucket="test_bucket", Key="test.txt").get()
>>> txt_file
{
    u'Body': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7fc5f0074f10>, 
    u'AcceptRanges': 'bytes', 
    u'ContentType': 'text/plain', 
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 
    'RetryAttempts': 0, 
        'HTTPHeaders': {
        'content-length': '17', 
        'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 
        'server': 'AmazonS3', 
        'last-modified': 'Sat, 06 Jul 2019 02:13:45 GMT', 
        'date': 'Sat, 06 Jul 2019 15:58:21 GMT', 
        'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256', 
        'content-type': 'text/plain'
        }
    }
}
```

Accessing a .docx Document I notice that the content-length is 0 (while the document has the same string written to the .txt file) and calling txt_file.read() outputs the empty string u''

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
word_file = s3.get_object(Bucket="test_bucket", Key="test.docx").get()
>>> word_file
{
    u'Body': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7fc5f0074f10>, 
    u'AcceptRanges': 'bytes', 
    u'ContentType': 'binary/octet-stream', 
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 
    'RetryAttempts': 0, 
        'HTTPHeaders': {
        'content-length': '0', 
        'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 
        'server': 'AmazonS3', 
        'last-modified': 'Thu, 04 Jul 2019 21:51:53 GMT', 
        'date': 'Sat, 06 Jul 2019 15:58:30 GMT', 
        'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256', 
        'content-type': 'binary/octet-stream'
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the content-length of both files to output the number of bytes in the file, however, only the .txt file is returning data.

Comment: A docx document is a *zip package*, not a singe file.

Comment: @CindyMeister so how do I output the content of the zip package? I imagine I would have to unzip the file, but how would that work since the data isn't processed in the boto3 client read() method or the iter_items() method?